# Is there any limit on in how many different Android or iOS applications I can use the Firebase google-services.json configuration file

Tags: firebase, firebase-notifications

I have a situation where I plan to publish different applications for different clients but manage the datas in one single Firebase project.

I have already tested in 2 different applications in Android with different packages names and the real-time database was working fine. I need to know is this a policy breaking action?

Any detailed explanation about "client_info", "oauth_client", "api_key" and "services" object within the file is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of developers having hundreds of applications in a single project.  If you're not trying to ramp up to that scale, you won't have a problem.

Comment: Let's take the example of a hotel network. I plan to publish hundreds of applications that would do the same thing but managed by a single Firebase project application.

Comment: If your applications don't share the same user base, they shouldn't be in the same project.  Consider using a different project for each app, and use the Firebase management API to make it easier to manage those project programmatically.

Comment: I want to benefit mostly from Firebase-Notification. I already have the backend build in Laravel, I will input the datas in different topics and use Firebase in different applications. The goal is to use the Google's realtime response. Technically it was possible as I tested. I'm more concerned by the policy. And also I'm not very sure about the sections that I welcomed any information in my question above.